# Fatal error: Call to undefined method in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

When i am trying to save a module details, it shows the below error, 
i don't know what is the mistake over there, but the data's are stored but every time i try to save i get this error.

**ERROR**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerPaymentIcicipg::redirect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\usa\admin\controller\payment\icicipg.php on line 18
```

**my code**

http://pastebin.com/gH4eefSM

Comment: Plz include ur code in the question body.

Comment: @Arin I was not able to paste lengthy code here so, add the code in pastebin, kindly  click the link for code

Comment: The problem is that the pastebin data will disappear in a month or so but the question will be here for ever. Cut the code you paste to just the relevant code that reproduces the problem. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it says "It seems your Question is mostly code kindly add some text"

Comment: Which Opencart version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the conclusion, that the method `redirect()` can only be undefined, if you were using Opencart 2.x, so please ignore my comment about which version you use.

In Opencart 2.0 `$this->redirect()` has been changed to `$this->response->redirect()`. So line 17 should look something like this:

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/payment', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
```

An even better way of doing it (by keeping it compatible with Opencart 1.5.x) would be something, like this:

```
if (version_compare(VERSION, '2.0', '>=')) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/payment', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
} else {
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/payment', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
}
```